# Which Python test framework to use?

Tags: python, framework

I will be working on automating a small Web app and i choose python and webdriver(selenium) for doing it depending on my comfort on coding with python. I had read few articles about Page object design. But i am currently confused on which test framework to use. I have some familiarity with unittest. When i pose this question to my acquantainces i only get suggestions of doing it in Java/TestNG/Junit.

Is there any equivalent or close which i can use with python. If you could point out some differnces on the majorly used test framework in python, it will be great for me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#Python

Answer (score 3):

> [PyUnit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/) - the standard unit testing framework for Python
>
> This unit testing framework, dubbed 'PyUnit' by convention, is a
>   `Python language version of JUnit`. JUnit was written by smart cookies
>   Kent Beck and Erich Gamma, and is, in turn, a Java version of Kent's
>   Smalltalk testing framework. Each is the de facto standard unit
>   testing framework for its respective language, and therefore both are
>   a strong basis for an effective and elegant Python framework.

Comment: Any personal feedback about it?

Comment: Good question (+1). I don't code Java, so haven't used JUNIT. However, I have had a lot of experience of its derivative https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/ (and a little https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/, which is also derivative). There's a reason, of course, that they keep basing on Junit - it's good! Personally, I found CppUnit easy to learn, intuitive, in fact, way back then. Powerful, flexible  ... it's a darn good tool. Having used it, PhpUnit just came naturally.  I did try a few others (I forget which), but PhpUnit seemed the clear choice to me.

Comment: [py.test](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Nose and proboscis are popular test frameworks for python. I have been using nose for the last 3 years for our projects. Nose provides easy to install and use features which can help with providing Coverage , html or xml reporting, logging and running tests is super simple with nose. 
You can install using this command on the command line : 
"pip install nose"

You can find the documentation for nose here "http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"